# Edit method in EmployeeStore

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey im having trouble with my edit method in the EmployeeStore.  Basically im trying to ask the user to search through the map for an employee by name and then i want to print out the employee they search for and then i want to let the user edit the 3 variables of the employee class.  Can anyone help.  Here is my code:

```
Edit choice in the mainApp
  case 5:
           System.out.println("Edit");
           Employee employee2 = MenuMethods.userInput();
           Store.searchByName(employee2.getEmployeeName());
         if (employee2 != null)
        {
            employee2.setEmployeeName("Joe");
            employee2.setEmployeeId(1);
            employee2.setEmployeeEmail("webmail.com");
           Store.edit(employee2);
           Store.print();
        }

            break;
```

MenuMethods

```
//Imports
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************

public class MenuMethods 
{
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    //Methods for the Company Application menu.
    //Method for validating the choice.
         public static int getMenuChoice(String menuString, int limit, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
         {
                System.out.println(menuString);
                int choice = inputAndValidateInt(1, limit, prompt, errorMessage);
                return choice;
         }
    //********************************************************************
    //This method is used in the getMenuChoice method.
            public static int inputAndValidateInt(int min, int max, String prompt, String errorMessage) 
            {
                int number;
                boolean valid;
                do {
                    System.out.print(prompt);
                    number = keyboard.nextInt();
                    valid = number <= max && number >= min;
                    if (!valid) {
                        System.out.println(errorMessage);
                    }
                } while (!valid);
                return number;
            }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInput()
    {
         String temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         Employee e = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee ID:");
         int employeeId = keyboard.nextInt();
         temp = keyboard.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee E-mail address:");
         String employeeEmail  = keyboard.nextLine();
         return e = new Employee(employeeName , employeeId, employeeEmail);

    }
    //********************************************************************
    public static Employee userInputByName()
    {

         Employee employee = null;
         System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
         String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
         return employee = new Employee(employeeName , null, null);

    }
    //********************************************************************



}
```

EmployeeStore

```
//Imports.
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
//********************************************************************
public class EmployeeStore
{
    HashMap<String, Employee> map;
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

//Constructor.  
    public EmployeeStore()
    {
        map = new HashMap<String,Employee>();
    }
//********************************************************************
//Hashmap Methods.
//Add to the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void add(Employee employee)
    {

        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Remove from the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void remove(String key)
    {
      //Remove the Employee by name.
        map.remove(key);
    }
//********************************************************************
//Clear the Hashmap : Employee.
    public void clear()
    {
        map.clear();
    }
    //********************************************************************
//Print the Hashmap : Employee. 
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("\n********Employee's in the Company.********");
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            //System.out.println(employee); to print the toString of Employee class
            //or:
            System.out.println("Employee Name:\t" + employee.getEmployeeName());
            System.out.println("Employee Id:\t" + employee.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println("E-mail:\t"+ employee.getEmployeeEmail());
        }

    }
    public Employee get(String name){
        return map.get(name);
    }
    /*public void searchByName ()
    {
        //(for(Employee e : map.values()) {...}) 
        //and check for each employee if his/her email matches the searched value
        for(Employee e : map.values())
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            map.equals(getClass());

        }
    }*/
//********************************************************************
    public Employee searchByName(String name) 
    {
        Employee employee = map.get(name);    
        System.out.println(employee);
        return employee;
    }
//********************************************************************

    public Employee searchByEmail(String email) 
    {
        for (Employee employee : map.values())
        {
            if (email.equals(employee.getEmployeeEmail()))
            {
                System.out.println(employee);
                return employee;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
//********************************************************************
    public void edit(Employee employee)
    {
        map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
    }


//********************************************************************


//********************************************************************  
//********************************************************************


}
```

Comment: I see wants, requirements and code, but no specific question. What problems is your code currently having?

Comment: You should start replacing your comments with true javaDoc.

Comment: As @Hovercraft already mentioned - what *exactly* is your question? Furthermore, please post just the *relevant* parts of your code.

Comment: Hey,  Ive been at this for ages and i cannot figure it out.  Apoligies for the format.  bascially i cant get the right setup for the edit method because of errors.  the userinout method cannot be changed because of the parameters of the constructor of employee.  Therefore i cannot only ask the user to search for the name.

Comment: What errors? If you have coding errors, you need to tell us. If you've tried to solve this but run into problems, you need to show us.

Comment: The error is to do with the userInputByName method.  The constructor takes 3 args i need it to take only name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (persistance) store shouldn't have an edit method at all. It should provide methods to

- C - create a new item
- R - read an item
- U - update an existing item
- D - delete an existing item

Editing is done by an editor, that will make use of the stores create method (for new items) or read and update methods (for editing existing items)

---

for the `userInputByName` - get the name from the keyboard and use the store to return the employee, if any:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the Employee Name:");
String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
return getStore().searchByName();
```

You only have find a way to implement the magic `getStore()` method so that you get the instance of the employee store that can provide the employees.

Comment: While this is technically correct (1+), the ultimate authority over what his EmployeeStore should include or exclude will be his published assignment requirements.

Comment: If the assignment clearly specifies an edit funtion on the store then he should have a talk with his prof :D